# Requesting endorsement for arxiv from future professor as a high-school graduate

Tags: publications, professorship, arxiv, independent-researcher

I finished high-school, and would like to publish articles on arxiv. I got into university, and found out that a professor of the institue of mathematics is submitting papers to the site. I start my first semester next month, and do not know him, however I would like to publish an article this week.

Is it a good idea to ask for endorsement from him? If so, what is the “best” way to ask?

I would like to do research in the future too, as I am extremely interested in the subject (analysis) and I have been learning it for a long time.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I rearranged your question a bit so that it cannot be read that your question is about asking for ArXiv endorsement and research opportunities at the same time. Should that have been your intention, please ask a separate question for the latter.

Comment: What do you mean by an endorsement? If he doesn't know you and hasn't seen your work how could he endorse it?

Comment: @Murhpy Endorsement is required to publish on arxiv. Thats why I asked, since I do not know anyone who can endorse yet. I will ask him if he wants to read my paper as well.

Comment: I took a peek at your website. I would suggest that you *not* send your professor your "proof" of the Riemann Hypothesis...

Comment: @Jeff I would like to find mistakes in it. If no-one reads it, I wont know where I have gone wrong. Btw, I do not claim that the "proof" is correct, just another attempt, which may have some new ideas. I wont lose anything I think, if I politely asking it, since it is not very long.

Comment: The arXiv is not the correct place for such an article. The purpose of the arXiv is the dissemination of publication-ready papers. It would be better to simply wait until you have established a relationship with a professor, and then you can ask that professor personally to take a look at your ideas (or, even better, you can meet and discuss them together). Besides, it is very unlikely any professor would be willing to endorse a supposed 3-page proof of RH....which is exactly why the endorsement system is in place.

Comment: @pndev One more note: Once a paper has been accepted on the arXiv, you *cannot* remove it. If you plan to continue doing research in the future, you do not want such a blemish on your "permanent record".

Comment: @Jeff I have not sent my mail yet. I know that RH is a very sensitive topic. I would really like my method reviewed, and I still don't know where can I get some feedback (on MSE they only told me it is similar to the reformulation including the bounds on the mertens function, and I do not want to bomb MSE with these kind of questions). I have seen many claim-to-be proofs of famous problems on arxiv, so I tough it can be reviewed there by others. But if I cannot remove it, I wont post it fully until I know which parts are correct.

Comment: The arXiv is definitely not the right place.  Most of the papers on famous problems you've seen there are crackpot work (appearing there only because the arXiv errs on the side of caution in rejecting submissions - none of them would be there if it were easy to filter out junk submissions without accidentally filtering out some good ones too).  They are generally ignored, with no feedback for the author, and serve only to make the author look bad.

Comment: I decided to wait for a personal discussion, since I do not have enough knowledge to make sure every step is right, and dont know how to get it reviewed. Thanks for the advices! Anyway the answer encouraged me to contact him as soon as I get into college.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds to me like a great opportunity to introduce yourself and possibly find a mentor relationship in the bargain.

Just be succinct and straight-forward about who you are and what led you to contact this particular professor.  I would also recommend taking the opportunity to invite the professor to give you feedback, which 1) may be sorely needed and 2) might be the beginning finding some interesting research connections as an undergraduate.

An email you write might go something like this:

> Hello, Professor Ridcully:
>
> You don't know me yet, but I'm going to be a student at Unseen University this Fall, and I am interested in mathematical research.  I've already been working some on my own, and have put together a manuscript that I would like to post on arXiv.  I'm contacting you because I need somebody to endorse my submission, and noticed that you have recently posted on arXiv as well.  If you would be interested in giving me feedback on this work, I would be interested in that as well.
>
> Please let me know if you are willing to help, and I will send you my manuscript.

Comment: I am not 100% convinced about starting an e-mail to an unfamiliar professor with "Hello, ".

Comment: Thanks! I am glad it is not rude to ask, but a great opportunity. btw in my language I change "Hello" to a formal greeting:)

Comment: Oh, and one more: what could be the subject of the email? I will ask another question if necessary.

Comment: @pndev To each their own preferred "neutral" greeting; I personally find "Dear" to be a bit old-fashioned.  For a subject, I would again recommend going direct, e.g., "Future student requesting help with an arXiv submission"

Comment: "Incoming freshman" might be clearer than "future student".